# Citations undefined - Bibliography not compatible with with author-year

Tags: bibliographies, errors, texmaker

NOTE: Edited changes to bibliographystyle --> now \bibliographystyle{acm}

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{natbib}

\title{Literature Review: \\
\textbf{Farms: \\
 Supply}}


\author{ Jane }
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter*{\textit{Introduction}}
Some Text\cite{Nielsen2011}.

More text \cite{Byrne2003}.


\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{literature_review_references}


\end{document}
```

The citation is causing me trouble. I have another citation in a different section that worked the first time but after adding the second citation and running again, I now get the error stated at the top.

I have my compile settings as:
Latex
Bibtex
Latex
Latex
View Pdf (evince)

Ok so I have also removed the PdfLaTeX command in my compile line.

The .bbl file looks like:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{Byrne2003}
{\sc Byrne, B.~W., and Houlsby, G.~T.}
\newblock Foundations for offshore wind turbines.
\newblock {\em Philosophical Transactions: Mathematical, Physical and
  Engineering Sciences 361}, 1813 (2003), pp. 2909--2930.

\bibitem{Nielsen2011}
{\sc Nielsen, J.~J., and Sorensen, J.~D.}
\newblock On risk-based operation and maintenance of offshore wind turbine
  components.
\newblock {\em Reliability Engineering and System Safety 96\/} (2011),
  218--229.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Ok I changed the bibliography style so now it gets past Process started.

New errors!

- citations undefined (again, this was working originally but now are undefined?)

  Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Well, for one, you have nothing between `\begin{document}` and the first `\end{document}`, so nothing will be output. Later on, in the part of the file that's currently ignored since it's after `\end{document}`, you have unbalanced braces (the `\chapter*{` is not closed). Furthermore, don't mix engines in your compile sequence (you start with `latex` and finish with `pdflatex`)—this will cause issues with graphics formats, etc. Choose the engine you need and use it all the way through.

Comment: Additional notes: You don't need the switch `\makeatother` unless you used the switch `\makeatletter` at some previous point in the file (because `@` is "other" by default). If you want to use `\maketitle` to print the title page, you should set `\title{My Title}` and `author{Name}` somewhere before `\maketitle`.

Comment: also don't use `fullpage` (you are already using `geometry` which is better) and don't use `epsfig` (unless you are emulating documents written in the 1980's with the latex2.09 epsfig style) `[latin 1]` should be `[latin1]` (it works but only by accident) don't load `geometry` twice (the second one is ignored anyway but it is confusing and can lead to option clashes to load packages multiple times)

Comment: Paul- thanks for spotting some of those mistakes! I think texmaker stuck the end document in there without me noticing. I'm confused though on compile sequence.. I had it just as Latex > Bibtex > Latex >Latex before and that wasn't work, and I saw somewhere a suggestion to add the pdfLatex and the evince command, which did make it work. What is the problem with doing this?

Comment: Also, I do have the title and author in before \maketitle, I just deleted it for the purpose of posting it here

Comment: David - I'm not seeing where I load geometry twice?

Comment: Ok I made the suggested changes but I still have it saying :process started, then immediately process exited with errors

Comment: Please edit your post with a _minimal_ (start removing packages one-by-one; if the error still occurs, the package has nothing to do with your current problem) example that exhibits the problem. Also, when replying to comments, please use @user3306583 (@ followed by the user name) syntax to notify the comment author.

Comment: @PaulGessler - Ok I edited the code here with suggested changes but still the same problem. Please note: this was compiling correctly with citations included and stopped working when I added another citation (no other changes!) it doesn't even display errors, just says the process exited with errors.

Comment: If the problem started with a new citation, it is most likely a problem with that entry in your bibtex database (literature_review_references.bib). But we don't have this file, so can't help you further. And quite frankly, I can't see how this file successfully compiled with `\chapter*{\textit{Introduction}` and `\maketitle` without `\title{...}` (both of these will throw errors).

Comment: lines 7 and 12 load geometry

Comment: Do you get the problem _with the document you have posted here_  (ie do what we do cut the text from the website and save as a new file) if not please edit the example so that it demonstrates the problem.

Comment: As I said, it did compile successfully but I do have the \title and \author in (I've added back in some arbitrary information here) but I deleted it to post. Currently, I am running what I have posted here with the exception that I have a section and a paragraph of written work. If I remove the citation, I still have the same problem. It won't compile anything actually! Maybe an issue with texmaker?

Comment: I highly doubt it is an issue with TexMaker. Until you take your file, reduce it to a minimal example that shows the issue, and post that _exact_ file here, we are only guessing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I have edited with your requests. This is the full document. I have replaced any of the text just with the words "Text"

Comment: @user3306583 did you read the complete error message? Did you then consult the `natbib` documentation as it recommends?

Answer (score 1):

I took your code and tried to compiled. Some errors appeared but they can be fixed doing the following (also take a look to he comments about `\usepackage{fullpage}`, `\makeatother` and `\chapter*{` with no `}` at the end of the line.):

- Add in preambule: `\autor{your name}`, `\title{your report title}` and `\date{today}`, this way the command `\maketitle` produces no error.
- Remove the `\end{document}` command after `\begin{document}` line. You must have just one `\end{document}` in your file.
- Close the brackets in `\chapter*{\textit{Introduction}}` command. Always check that every `{` has to end with a `}` at the end of the given command, in your code `\chapter*{` open one and `\textit{` opens another, then this line must end with `}}`, one for each command.

I compiled it, successfully with the next code, adding the details described before:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[latin 1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{natbib}
\makeatother

\title{test}
\author{you}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter*{\textit{Introduction}}

 ...... cost of energy and can be up to 30\% \cite{Wilkes2012}. 

\bibliographystyle{apastyle}
\bibliography{literature_review_references}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @hkvictor - Thanks for this, I took note of the syntax errors and edited the code I had. I deleted my title and author name from the code that I posted purely for privacy reasons although this is included in my document.

HOWEVER.. despite fixing these, I still have the problem originally stated:
Process Started

Process Exited with error(s)

This just started after compiling successfully before!

Comment: I saw your edited post after answering this. When you remove personal information, just keep the commands (even empty or with false info, like I did).